# Error after compiling C code

Tags: c, compiler-errors

I get this problem while compiling my code.

```
Error 14 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _findFuncs referenced in function _main H:\pshtoolkit_v1.4-src\whosthere\whosthere.obj whoisthere-alt
```

What libraries should I link with visual studio in order to resolve the error?

Comment: _findFuncs is such a generic name that it may be difficult to link it to an usual library. Can you provide us with more info? Are you using a function named findFuncs in your code?If not, wich libraries are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*What libraries should I link with visual studio*:
The library containing _findFuncs.

OK, not helpful I know, but presumably you know what findFuncs is and you are calling it for a reason.  Where did you find out about it?  Do you have any documentation?

Maybe you have a typo calling this function (case?), e.g. should it be FindFuncs?

Or is it defined somewhere as a static function?

Answer (score 2):

I have solved the error, it is not the problems with the libraries. The .c file which contains the fincFuncs method had not been properly referenced. Thanks for helping though!

Answer (score 0):

It's actually Linker error which your compiler doesn't resolve that name I think just 
do forward declartion for the symbol which you are using in main.
May be you have done forward declaration but missing the definition itself.
Which your linker is looking for
Here it's your function `"findfunc"`
Check whether it works or not

Comment: How should forward declaration help here? As you mentioned: The linker is missing the symbol, not the compiler.

Comment: Actually external symbols are resolved by linker and as you have given your error message which completely says about this

Comment: this findfunc must be declared somewhere either in the current file or in some header... If its already there then the definition which your linker is looking for is not available so it's generating error

Comment: Yes, you name it: It's all about the **definition** not the **declaration** ... @Omkant